# Unable to decode Firebase JWT

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am creating a web application and I want to implement Firebase authentication and help users to login using Google, Facebook or Twitter.

Users login using Firebase on my website I receive login information in my Javascript.

As per [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), instead of passing UID received in the JS, I send the token id to the backend server so that it can authenticate the source and retrieve the user id.

I use [PHP-JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to check and validate the token returned by Firebase. However, the `Key ID` in the header is not matching with any of the `Key ID` defined in https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com where, as per the [verification document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), is where I can find the public keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out the 'iss' and 'exp' fields in the Firebase token payload when your server can not validate the token? The issuer ('iss') should start with https://securetoken.google.com/, and the issued time ('iat') should be 1-2 seconds earlier than your system time when your server received the token.

Comment: 'iss' => 'accounts.google.com'
   'exp' => 1484310143

When I try with facebook or twitter I get "Wrong number of segments" thrown from PHP-JWT.

As you said earlier, ISS should start with securetoken.google.com, but somehow it shows accounts.google.com!

Comment: The token your server received ('iss' => 'accounts.google.com') is actually a Google OAuth2 IdToken, nor Firebase token. You may find FirebaseUI Javascript library (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) helpful as a starting point to implement Google/Facebook/Twitter login with Firebase.

Comment: That is the interesting part. I am indeed using firebaseui. Added as per instructions on https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web